# If a druid is targeted by the Command spell while in Wild Shape, whose Wisdom modifier is used?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape, ability-scores

When a druid is in the Wild Shape form, and the *command* spell is used on them, do they use the player character's Wisdom modifier or the animal's?

Answer (score 13):

## A Wild-Shaped Druid retains their original Wisdom Score

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, **but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature**. If the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature's bonus instead of yours. If the creature has any legendary or lair actions, you can't use them.
>
> —**Druid**, Player's Handbook, pg. 67

So if the *Command* spell, or any other effect that triggers an Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma Saving Throw against the druid, is applied when they are in their wild-shape form, they would use their original stats to make the save.

The only exception is if they wild-shape into a creature that, for whatever reason, has a better Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma saving throw than the Druid's normal statistics; in which case the Druid would instead use the beast's stats instead. This is extremely unlikely for Intelligence or Wisdom Saving Throws, due to the Druid's innate proficiency in both those saving throws, but it could be probable with a Charisma Saving Throw.

Comment: thanks very much i kind of thought so but couldn't find the answer in writing lol

Comment: Good catch about an animal with higher ability scores!